# SQL Queries that show detailed MRR breakdowns

Tags: sql

My company is rapidly growing and our current MRR tracker (Chart Mogul) doesn't differentiate the different buckets in MRR due to the free trial one of our products offer. I need to build a SQL Code for Stripe Sigma that will break down the amount of Total MRR and shows up as the different MRR Buckets. Those buckets being New Business, Expansion, Contraction, Churn & Reactivation. Thanks.

I've tried running a few queries but they always show up as errors. Mainly due to data used from previous runs.

Small bit of an example here :

```
select distinct
    invoices.customer_id as customer,
    invoices.id as stripe_invoice,
    invoice_line_items.period_start as subscription_start,
    invoice_line_items.period_end as subscription_end,
    date_trunc('month', invoice_line_items.period_start) as recognition_start,
    date_add('month', -1, invoice_line_items.period_end) as recognition_end,
    invoices.currency as currency,
    (invoices.amount_due - coalesce(invoices.tax, 0)) / 100.0 as collected_amount_excl_tax
```

Customer.id error